# How to access a view inside the layout of a Preference, Android

Tags: java, android, layout, preference, preferencefragment

I have a PreferenceScreen with several PreferenceCategories. Each Preference has a custom layout. This layout contains a TextView. My goal is to get access to this TextView in the Java code to modify its text. Here is my example:

In the PreferenceScreen XML file

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    .
    .
    .
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:key="versionCategory"
        android:layout="@layout/preference_category_layout_version" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

In the preference_category_layout_version XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- The layout for the preferenceCategory "VERSION" -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/versionTextContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Version 1.3"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I can find my preference in the PreferenceFragment Java code using `findPreference`. I tried to inflate the layout and access the TextView using `findViewById`. However, setting the text did not work :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    .
    .
    .

    View rootView = View.inflate(getActivity(), findPreference("versionCategory").getLayoutResource(), null);
    TextView textView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.versionTextContainer);
    textView.setText("Hello World");
}
```

I wonder if there is a better approach to access a child view inside a custom layout of a Preference ?